# Choose record based on varying condition

Tags: aggregate

I have a table that a primary key that can have one to two different status' associated with it. It looks like this:

```
Key Status
123 Book
123 Change
122 Book
121 Book
121 Change
```

If there is a record that has status of 'Change' then I only want to select that record and not the record with the same key that has a status of 'Book'.  If the key only has a status of 'Book'  then I always want to choose that record.  It is not possible to have a status of 'Change' without having a status of 'Book' first.

This is what I would like to see returned:

```
Key Status
123 Change
122 Book
121 Change
```

Any help?

Comment: To obtain fully correct answer you must specify: 1) your DBMS (including version) 2) full list of possible `Status` values (or clarify it is dynamic).

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT Key, MAX(Status) FROM Table
GROUP BY Key
```

Nice and simple - works because *Change* is after *Book* when ordered by the MAX aggregate function.